# Delete items unchecked from a form using ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

When a user deselects an item (by unchecking the checkbox) from the form, I want the corresponding data to be deleted from  the database.

Here is what my form looks like:

```
                                   Category
   Item                           80     626

1.Item # 1 (87)                   chk    chk
2.Item # 2 (59)                   chk    chk
```

So basically, the list looks like this:

```
DB_list =  (80|87, 626|87, 80|59, 626|59)
```

Now if a user deselects one of these items `80|87`, I want it to be deleted from the database like so:

```
DELETE FROM TBL 
WHERE  Item = 87 
AND    Category = 80
```

So on form submit, the list becomes

```
 New_List = (626|87, 80|59, 626|59)
```

How do we delete `80|87`?

Comment: If you are only storing the two id's (no other related values), another approach is to delete all records for each category, and repopulate based on what *is* checked. Like the "diff" approach, it has pros and cons. The advantage is simpler code and typically less db queries (overall) than the "diff" approach. The disadvantage is it executes a db query every time, even if nothing is change. Whichever approach you take, be sure to wrap the queries in a cftransaction to maintain data consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
        <cfoutput>
        <cfset DB_list  = "80|87,626|87,80|59,626|59" />
        <cfset New_List = DB_list />
        <cfset myitems="80,626">
        <cfset mycategories = "87,59"/>

        <cfif structKeyExists(form,"fieldnames")>
            <!-- on submit -->
            <cfif structKeyExists(form,"listitem")>
              <cfset New_List = form.listitem>
            </cfif>

            <br />RESULT:<br />
            DB_list:#DB_list#<br />
            New_List:#New_List# <br /><br />

            <cfloop from="1" to="#ListLen(DB_list)#" index="ix">
                <cfset listitem = ListGetAt(DB_list,ix)>
                <cfif ListFindNoCase(New_List,listitem) eq 0>
                    <!-- hence: split in javascript -->
                    <cfset listitemarray=ListToArray(listitem,"|")/>
                    <cfset itemid=listitemarray[1] />
                    <cfset categoryid=listitemarray[2] />
                    <cfquery>
                    DELETE FROM TBL 
                    WHERE Item = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#itemid#">
                    AND Category = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#categoryid#">
                    </cfquery>
                </cfif>
            </cfloop>


        </cfif>

        <form name="tstForm" id="tstForm" method="post" action="">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <cfloop from="1" to="#ListLen(mycategories)#" index="lstindex1">
                        <td>Category #ListGetAt(mycategories,lstindex1)#</td>
                    </cfloop>
                </tr>
                <cfloop from="1" to="#ListLen(myitems)#" index="lstindex2">
                    <tr>
                        <cfset itemid=#ListGetAt(myitems,lstindex2)# />
                        <td>item #itemid#</td>
                        <cfloop from="1" to="#ListLen(mycategories)#" index="lstindex3">
                            <cfset catid=#ListGetAt(mycategories,lstindex3)# />
                            <td> 
                                <input type="checkbox" id="listitem_#itemid#_#catid#" name="listitem" value="#itemid#|#catid#" <cfif ListFindNoCase(New_List,"#itemid#|#catid#",",") gt 0>checked</cfif>/>
                            </td>
                        </cfloop>
                    </tr>
                </cfloop>
            </table>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </cfoutput>
```

Run this code [here](http://cflive.net/)

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to have a hidden field in the form that has all the available values for the checkboxes.  Then when the form is submitted, compare what's in the hidden form field with what's in the checkbox field.  Whatever the hidden field has that the check box field does not can be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Without the use of JavaScript, Dan Bracuk's solution would work the best for your stated requirements. However, another simpler approach to this problem is to just `delete` all previous choices then re-`insert` whatever items are still checked. Then there is no need to compare old and new values to determine what has changed.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
DELETE
FROM   tbl
WHERE  NOT CONVERT(varchar(20), Item) + '|' + CONVERT(varchar(20), Category) 
    IN <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_varchar" value="#form.new_list#" list="yes">
```

Comment: The db engine was not specified.  Whatever db engine he has may or may not have a convert function.

Answer (score 0):

My approach using sql server is to delete all the list items from the db, and then add only the ones that have been submitted by the form. All delete and add queries should be put into a single transaction, so if anything fails you can make o rollback.